# Effective Java. Serializable Builder pattern (how to add public no-arg constructor?)

Tags: java, builder, effective-java

I want to create a class in Joshua Bloch's style using Builder pattern. But I want to use this class as DTO object and transfer it from EJB. So it need to have public no-arg constructor. How I can achieve this java-bean style in builder pattern? In Effective Java object have only one constructor which accepts `Builder` object as argument. If I add there public no-arg constructor, then I lost advantage of builder over Java-bean pattern.

Comment: You probably want to make the _builder_ a bean, then, and have your definitive object be the result of this builder's `.build()`.

Comment: @fge yes, you are right. I want to make builder a bean (because I can transfer only beans from EJB).

Comment: Passing builders around like this is a design smell to me. Builders should be short-lived artefacts used to construct the objects you want to pass around.

Comment: @McDowell I want to use builder for security reasons. i.e. when client builds object and pass it to EJB method, this object can be in inconsistent state. I want to prevent client from creating object in inconsistent state. 

Why this is design smell to you? Because builder pattern increases size of transfered object (adding builder it's at least having copy of all class fields inside inner class)?

Comment: @MyTitle Maybe I'm missing something, but the solution discussed in the comments just seems to move the problem from the bean to the builder. Beans (with no-args ctors; getters/setters) are mutable. The builder can be passed in an invalid state and I don't see an advantage over adding an `isValid` method to the bean (or some other validation mechanism.)

Comment: You can have applied builder pattern and still have dummy no args constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what is making you to use builder pattern here but here is what my experience says to your issue.

1. You are using EJBs. So, i assume that you are in distributed application mode.
2. Your DTO will be used for carrying data to and from EJB. So, you should consider making your this DTO serializable (Now, having a no argument constructor makes sense).

According to me, all you need is some kind of transformer which accepts obj1 from some layer for processing and then return it.

I would recommend builder to be used only in case where your object construction is a multi-step process (for example, user registration).

Comment: Thanks. Can you provide some more explanation about transformer?

Comment: buddy!!! transformer is anything that converts objA to objB like ObjectB b = new ObjectB(); <br/> b.setPropert1(obja.getSomeProperty());

Answer (score 0):

If you use Lombok to create `@Builder` implementation. You can use `@Jacksonized` annotation for serialization and deserialization.
read more in the [official docs](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/Jacksonized)